# PowerShell. Increase Count in ForEach-Object -Parallel

Tags: powershell

I'd like to use ForEach-Object -Parallel to whitelist IPs for Azure Web Apps. This is normally done like this:

```
Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup1" -WebAppName "WebApp1" -Name "IP-100" -Priority "100" -Action Allow -IpAddress "10.0.0.0/24"
```

The approach that I had in mind, with changing count, as in changing IP-100 to IP-101, Priority from 100 to 101 doesn't work, as `ForEach-Object -Parallel` is using [isolated runspaces](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature/):

> Each runspace must load whatever module is needed and have any
> variable be explicitly passed in from the calling script. The only
> variable that automatically appears in the parallel script block is
> the piped in object.

How can I run such script in parallel, something like this?

```
$Count = 100
Get-Content UniqueIPs.txt | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup1" -WebAppName "WepApp1" -Name "IP-$using:Count" -Priority "$using:Count" -Action Allow -IpAddress "$IP/24" -WhatIf
    $Count ++
} -ThrottleLimit 5
```

Without -Parallel I usually did it like this:

```
foreach($IP in $IPs1)
{
  Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup1" -WebAppName "WebApp1" -Name "IP-$name" -Priority "$priority" -Action Allow -IpAddress "$IP/24"
  $name ++
  $priority ++
}
```

Comment: Try building a hashtable for each entry *before* you apply the settings - e.g. ```Get-Content UniqueIPs.txt | foreach-object -begin { $count = 1}; { @{"ip"=$_; "priority"=$count}; count++; }``` and then piping **that** into your parallel foreach. You already know the priority of each entry then without having to track a counter in the parallel loop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this is assign each IP a priority before passing it to your parallel `ForEach` loop:

```
$priority = 100
$IPs = '10.0.0.1','10.0.0.2','10.0.0.3'
$list = foreach ($IP in $IPs) { 
    $IP|select @{l='IP';e={$_}},@{l='Priority';e={$priority}}
    $priority++
}

# $list Outputs:
IP       Priority
--       --------
10.0.0.1      100
10.0.0.2      101
10.0.0.3      102
```

Then you just run what you have already:

```
$list | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    Add-AzWebAppAccessRestrictionRule -ResourceGroupName "ResourceGroup1" -WebAppName "WepApp1" -Name "IP-$($_.Priority)" -Priority $_.Priority -Action Allow -IpAddress "$($_.IP)/24" -WhatIf
}
```